# Redraw Highcharts using Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I would like to use checkboxes (most likely jQuery UI buttons - http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox) to change the data in my highcharts graph

So by default, everything would show and then I'd have menus/sets of checkboxes to alter the data. One of the menus/sets would determine which which series to show but the others would filte the data

I presume posting to an external ASP page and retrieving the results via JSON would be best but was wondering if there were any examples around this? If I select an option, how to pass/retrieve that data (along with other options that have been slected or not) and if I unselect it, how to remove the filter (along with other options that have been slected or not)

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare checkbox, then catch event (like click) and use setData() / addSeries / addPoint, which allows to modify chart "on the fly.

All functions are documented here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts